# Subtract Dates in Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The input to reducer is as follows

```
key: 12

List<values> : 
               1,2,3,2013-12-23 10:21:44

               1,2,3,2013-12-23 10:21:59

               1,2,3,2013-12-23 10:22:07
```

The output needed is as follows:

```
1,2,3,2013-12-23 10:21:44,15
1,2,3,2013-12-23 10:21:59,8
1,2,3,2013-12-23 10:22:07,0
```

Please note last column is 10:21:59 minus 10:21:44. Date(next) - Date(current)

I tried loading into memory and subtracting but it is causing java heap memory issue. Your help is highly appreciated. data size for this key is huge > 1 GB and not able to fit into main memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something along the lines of this pseudocode in your `reduce()` method:

```
long lastDate = 0;
V lastValue = null;

for (V value : values) {
    currentDate = parseDateIntoMillis(value);
    if (lastValue != null) {
        context.write(key, lastValue.toString() + "," + (currentDate - lastDate));
    }
    lastDate = currentDate;
    lastValue = value;
}
context.write(key, lastValue.toString() + "," + 0);
```

Obviously there will be tidying up to do but the general idea is fairly simple.

Note that because of your requirement to include the date of the next value as part of the current value calculation, the iteration through the values skips the first write, hence the additional write after the loop to ensure all values are accounted for.

If you have any questions feel free to ask away.

Comment: Please notice the output. value of last column, for the first record is, next record minus the current record. How do you handle first record ?

Comment: On the first iteration, nothing is written out, but the value object and date time (in milliseconds) of the first record is stored in the variables `lastValue` and `lastDate` respectively. On the second iteration, the current record is the second record, thus giving you all the information required to write out the *first* record's date (note it's writing out `lastValue`, not the current one) with the difference between records appended on the end. Due to this postponed writing out, in order to write out the very last record an additional `context.write` is required.

Answer (score 0):

you can do by following code

```
reduce (LongWritable key, Iterable<String> Values, context){
  Date currentDate = null;
  LongWritable  diff = new LongWritable();

 for (String value : values) {
    Date nextDate = new Date(value.toString().split(",")[3]);
    if (currentDate != null) {
        diff.set(Math.abs(nextDate.getTime()-currentDate.getTime())/1000)
        context.write(key, diff);
    }
    currentDate = nextDate;
}
```

}